# Unity unitybootstrapper issue

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I’ve upgraded my project today to Prism 7.0.0 and Unity 6.3. Before that, I had Prism 5 and Unity 4.

Now I’m running into problems with the Prism.Unity.UnityBootstrapper: it seems that the Container field is still a Microsoft.Practices.Unity.IUnityContainer instead of Unity.IUnityContainer.

I had hoped that the upgrade would cleanly cut all references to Microsoft.Practices.Unity off of my project, but it seems that I’m still forced to use the “old” Prism library, at least in parts.

Why does this situation arise, and what do I do to make it right? Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you sure you've removed references to Microsoft.Practises.Unit.IUnityContainer?

Answer (score 0):

> Why does this situation arise,

Because there are still references to the old versions of prism and/or unity in your project.

> and what do I do to make it right?

Remove all the old versions from your project's references.

> Am I missing something?

You're assuming that the update removed all the old dlls, which obviously is not the case.